# Why is there no movement of objects in the vector when additional memory is reserved?

Tags: c++, stdvector, move-semantics

There is the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test {
   public:
    Test() {}
    Test(int x) : x(x) {}

    Test(const Test&) noexcept = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test&) noexcept = delete;

    Test(Test&& r) noexcept { x = std::move(r.x); }
    Test& operator=(Test&& r) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move";
        x = std::move(r.x);

        return *this;
    }

    ~Test() noexcept { std::cout << x; }

   private:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Test> v;

    v.reserve(5);
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    v.emplace_back(3);
    v.emplace_back(4);
    v.emplace_back(5);
    v.reserve(10);
}
```

output:

```
1234512345
```

We see the destructors, but do not see the move assignment, so we can conclude that the object is being copied instead of moved.
This question has already been discussed in several topics, but nowhere is there a specific answer.

There is a workaround using unique_ptrs:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Test {
   public:
    Test() {}
    Test(int x) : x(x) {}

    Test(const Test&) noexcept = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test&) noexcept = delete;

    Test(Test&& r) noexcept { x = std::move(r.x); }
    Test& operator=(Test&& r) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move";
        x = std::move(r.x);

        return *this;
    }

    ~Test() noexcept { std::cout << x; }

   private:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Test>> v;

    v.reserve(5);
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test>(1));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test>(2));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test>(3));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test>(4));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Test>(5));
    v.reserve(10);
}
```

output:

```
12345
```

All code tested on compilers gcc 5.1 - 10.2

Why does copying of objects occur when allocating memory in a vector instead of moves? Why is the move semantics not used in the first block of code, what is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: it is unclear what is the "problem" or what you conclude from what. Please include the output and explain what else you expected

Comment: *"according to the destructor's output, we can conclude that the object is being copied"* - what does that mean? Even a moved from object has to call the destructor, so it's really unclear what you are observing

Comment: It is not clear to me how you reached the conclusion *"Where, according to the destructor's output, we can conclude that the object is being copied."*.

Comment: I really don't know whether this is helpful, but moving an `int` is the same as copying it. Were you expecting the original to be 0?

Comment: @NathanOliver He doesn't appear to have any codepaths that use that constructor though

Comment: @MooingDuck Yeah, just re-read the code.  comment removed.

Comment: Add `std::cout << "move ctor";` to `Test(Test&&)` and you can see what's happening.

Comment: I think might understand what is going on here, but without the you clarifying the output you don't like, this is just a guess.  When you move an `int`, you actually make a copy.  Moving only really applies to pointers.  When you move an object that hold a pointer, you set the pointer in the destination to the pointer's value and then you set the source pointer to null, that's basically what C++ move semantics does.  For an `int`, there is nothing to "move".  It just has a value so the destination gets the same value but there is no need to do anything to the source as there is no pointer.

Comment: When you `reserve` it causes a reallocation which requires all 5 of your elements to be move-constructed to new storage. Then, the old instances are destroyed (causing the first `12345`). At the end of `main` your vector is destroyed, causing the second set of `12345`.

Comment: @françois-andrieux The reason is that we have a static storage duration, as I understand it, and therefore the movement occurs?

Comment: @rededx [Static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) has a very specific meaning in C++, and it does not apply here. I am not sure exactly what your comment is asking.

Comment: @rededx You are mostly right, but when `std::vector` reallocates it will usually move, not copy. In your case, because you only inspect an `int`, you cannot distinguish between move and copy because move and copy are equivalent for an `int`.

Comment: You output "move" in the move-assignment, but you do not print anything in the move-constructor. Add a `std::cout << "move-construct";` there and you will see it is indeed called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `v.reserve(10);` causes your vector to reallocate its storage so it can accommodate at least 10 elements. Presuming `capacity` is less than 10, this is a four step process :

1. New storage is allocated, enough so `capacity` will be at least 10.
2. The elements from the previous storage need to be moved to the new storage. For each element in the previous storage, move that element's value into a new instance in the new storage.
3. Before the old storage can be freed, the moved-from instances still need to be destroyed. This causes each of their destructor to execute, which prints `12345` in your case. Notice that the moved-from instances each still have their old value of `x`. Moving an `int` is equivalent to copying it, the original value is unchanged.
4. The previous storage is now freed. The vector now uses the new storage, which contains equivalent elements but is larger than the previous storage was.

Finally, at the end of `main` your vector `v` has to be destroyed. This causes each of its elements to be destroyed as well, which causes each of the destructors to execute. This is the second set of `12345` that is printed.

With `std::unique_ptr` you only see one set of numbers (`12345`) because `unique_ptr`s are moved between the two storage, not `Test`s. The new moved-constructed instances of `std::unique_ptr<Test>` take ownership of the pointer and the old moved-from instances no longer own those pointers. When the instances from the previous storage are destroyed, their destructors do nothing (because they no longer own a pointer). You only see the destruction of your `Test` instances when `v` is destroyed at the end of `main`. Then, the `std::unique_ptr` instances that are destroyed *do* own pointers to `Test`, so it results in `Test` instances being `delete`d.

Edit : Note that you only instrumented your move assignment operator. `std::vector` will use the move constructor in this case, so you will not see `"move"` even when instances of `Test` are moved by `v`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've literally just come to the same conclusion. There was no complete explanation in the old questions, I hope someone else besides me will find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

Move constructor/operator should leave old object in an undefined but **valid** state. The compiler in this case chooses to leave it unchanged and simply copy the values. When each of these sets of objects get destructed (first after move and second with the `std::vector` destructor), they print the values you see.

Comment: `std::vector` is required to use the allocator to manage memory, and allocators do not have any `realloc` api, so this isn't possible.